# Overflow error : range()

Tags: python, python-2.7

While I was trying to find the largest prime factor of a number using the code below attached , I encountered `OverflowError: Python int too large to covert to C long`

```
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    if prime(n)==1:
        return n
    while n>0 and i<n:
        if n % i ==0:
            n = n/i
            div = i
            prime_factors(n)
        else:
            i+=1

return div

def prime(n):
    for i in xrange(2,n):
        if n%i ==0:
            return 0
    return 1

num = int(raw_input())
print prime_factors(num)
```

Can anyone please help find a solution to this ?

**P.S: I am a beginner in Python.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range()` creates a list in memory, which will raise an error if `n` is too large. You should use `xrange()` instead, which will create a lazy-evaluated generator object.

Comment: I tried using `xrange()` but still I am getting an error.